# Force image to a fixed size

Tags: .net, vb.net, image

All of the pictures we download or create have different sizes in which, most of the time, will not fit in the app that we create.
Is there a way to force a picture to *appear* in for example, A4 size?

For my specific question,
[image]
That is the whole window of the app, but the picture extends furthermore at the bottom, which is why, I want to *set the boundaries* more likely, force it to resize to *60%*  of the screen.

This is how I call the image

```
Dim cm As New customImageOverlay(mainMap.Position)
cm.MarkerImage = New Bitmap(My.Resources.ground_floor_plan)
' before I make it appear to the map I want to do something like this
' cm.size = form.clientrectagle - 40% - just something in my mind..
    objects.Markers.Add(cm)
' this is at form  load event, I am just adding the image as an overlay
' so there are no pictureboxes
```

Comment: what is "cm"? what type of object?...or what is the image ultimately displayed in/on?

Comment: Sorry, its just a declaration from `customImageOverlay` class :) I just add it as an *overlay* above the map. This is the other way that might work instead of creating new form and use buttons, which was the thing you answered yesterday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to calculate how big you want the image to be, then create a thumbnail of it:

```
Friend Function GetImageThumb(ByVal orgBmp As BitMap, 
                        ByVal w as Int32, h as Int32) As Bitmap

    Dim thumb As New Bitmap(w, h)

    Using g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(thumb)
        g.DrawImage(orgBmp , 0, 0, w + 1, h + 1)
    End Using
    Return thumb
End Function
```

More important perhaps is scaling.  Figure out whether you want to resize based on Width or Height, then calculate the new size based on that.

```
    ' get new Height Scaled from a set Width:
    Friend Function ScaledHeight(ByVal w As Integer, orgSize as Size) As Integer
        Dim scale As Single = CSng(orgSize.Height / orgSize.Width)
        Return CInt(w * scale)
    End Function

    ' get new Width scaled from the Height:
    Friend Function ScaledWidth(ByVal h As Integer, orgSize as Size) As Integer
        Dim scale As Single = CSng(orgSize.Width / orgSize.Height )
        Return CInt(h * scale)
    End Function
```

Look at the raw image, figure out the new size you want it to be, then determine the size of the thumb by scaling either the Width or Height (usually Height, for me), then using create a thumbnail using that new size.

**EDIT**

It is not really "fixed" unless all images you want to display have the very same dimensions, which is not usually the case.   Scaling is especially important when the screen has a different aspect ratio (W:H) than the image.

For a 60% sizing of the screen (pseudo code, you'll have to work some things out):

```
 Dim bmp as Bitmap = New Bitmap(My.Resources.ground_floor_plan)

 Dim orgSize As Size = bmp.Size

 ' scale to 60% of width
 Dim newWidth As Integer = (thisForm.Width * .6)
 ' maybe:
 'Dim newWidth As Integer = (My.Computer.Screen.WorkingArea.Width * .6)
 Dim newWidth As Int32 = ScaledHeight(newWidth, orgSize )

 Dim thumb as Bitmap = GetImageThumb(bmp, newWidth, newHeight)

 cm.MarkerImage = thumb
 objects.Markers.Add(cm)
 bmp.Dispose
```

Comment: How can I call this before I add my image? before `objects.Markers.add(cm)` .. isn't there something like `set image to 1024 x 640` ?

Comment: see edit for a rough out.  in some cases you may want to scale the other way depending on whether you want to show lots of the image or use more screen space.

Comment: Where should I declare orgSize?

Comment: `Dim orgSize As Size = bmp.Size`